# How to create an user-defined header file ? Hope , I would get that either in C/C++

Tags: c, c++14

I am an beginner in C++ language. I was able to understand the concept of header file , but facing the problem when i wanted to deal with them. I want to create a user-defined header files ?
Expecting someone to show me a sample of it!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "*I was able to understand the concept of header file*" -- If you really understood, you'd never ask this question. Basically, just put your API declarations in a file and name it `.h` (or `.hpp`).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? How to create the file? What should go in there? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

A header is just a C source file that generally only contains:

- Preprocessor `#define`s
- Type declarations
- Function declarations
- Comments :)

There's nothing magical to it.

This could be a fully valid entire header:

```
// Save this as "adding.h"
int add_numbers(int a, int b);
```

It would be used like this:

In the file `main.c`:

```
#include "adding.h"

int main(void)
{
  const int x = 12;
  const int y = 27;
  printf("the sum of %d and %d is %d\n", x, y, add_numbers(x, y));
  return 0;
}
```

Then you'd of course also have `adding.c`:

```
#include "adding.h"
int add_numbers(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

--

Sometimes, in real projects, headers `#include` other headers, and that can create problems with repeated definitions (and also costs compilation time). To protect against that, include guards are often added. It would look like this:

```
// In "adding.h".
#if !defined ADDING_H_
#define ADDING_H_
int add_numbers(int a, int b);
#endif  // ADDING_H_
```

The contents of the header is just wrapped in an `#if defined` block, with a `#define` of the checked-for symbol inside it. This makes sure that multiple inclusions during the compilation of a single C file are harmless.

Comment: For completeness you should mention [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: thank you for spending your valuable time ,